# Find and replace URLs with notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I want to change the urls in my exported wordpress xml post from:

https://example.net/blog/2012/12/04/postname/

to:

https://example.net/postname/

I tried some regular expressions reading other users here but i don't make it works.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that `example.net` is constant:

Find: `(https://example\.net)/blog/\d+/\d+/\d+(/[^/]+/)`

Replace: `$1$2`

That's it :)

Comment: Thans for your quick response, this works for the example... but my postname have numbers and dash signs/numbers and make a conflict, something like this:
https://example.net/blog/2012/12/04/long-name-with-111-and-dash/
Any clue to add this option?

Comment: @Kim yep! Matching on "not-a-slash". I modified my answer.

Comment: Really great! Thanks a lot.